# Can I write a SQL code where I have different aggregate columns that filter for different criteria?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot, case, aggregate-functions

I built a query where I joined an account table with an opportunity table.
My goal is to see every account along with columns that pull closed won opportunities $ and a column that pulls open pipeline $ using the same code.

So it would look more like the following. The query has to be filtered by stages to get both pipeline and closed won.

| Account ID | FY24 Pipeline | FY24 Closed Won |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | $xx.xx | $xx.xx |
| 2 | $xx.xx | $xx.xx |

I was able to successfully join the two tables, but I don't know how to create aggregate columns that are filtering for different criteria and are still grouped by account. I tried to build a subquery in the SELECT statement (seen below 'AS FY24 Pipeline'), but it brought back the total value of that filter and duplicated it for every account.

I am a bit new to BigQuery. Is this possible?

```
SELECT A.Account_ID, (SELECT SUM (ACV_Bookings_USD_Converted) FROM `Table 2` WHERE Segment = 'Enterprise' AND Opportunity_type = 'Revenue Opportunity' AND Stage IN ('Qualified', 'Proposal','Trial','Decision','Purchase','Closing') AND Billing_Country = 'Canada' AND Close_Year IN ('FY24')) AS FY24_Pipeline
FROM `Table 1` AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Table 2` AS O
ON A.account_id = O.Account_id
WHERE Enterprise_Assignment IS NOT NULL
AND A.Billing_Country = 'Canada'
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case` within the aggregate functions.

For the non-working subquery that you currently have, that would look like:

```
SELECT A.Account_ID, 
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN 
            O.Segment = 'Enterprise' 
            AND O.Opportunity_type = 'Revenue Opportunity' 
            AND O.Stage IN ('Qualified', 'Proposal','Trial','Decision','Purchase','Closing') 
            AND O.Billing_Country = 'Canada' 
        THEN O.ACV_Bookings_USD_Converted END
    ) AS FY24_Pipeline
FROM `Table 1` AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Table 2` AS O ON A.account_id = O.Account_id
WHERE Enterprise_Assignment IS NOT NULL AND A.Billing_Country = 'Canada'
GROUP BY 1
```

You can duplicate the logic for the other columns that you want to generate.

Note that it is good practice to prefix *all* columns in the query with the table they belong to: this makes for better readability and maintenance.

Comment: Quick Question. How would an IFNULL work with this?